# Is SQLite appropriate for off-line storage before replication to a server?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am planning on writing an application that saves a fair amount of data.  Historically, I have simply written data directly to a server, and only used some simple key/value storage with shared preferences for local storage.

I am considering this time, instead, using SQLite to save the information at first, and sync the data to the server in the background later.  This will benefit the user in a few ways: 1) can use the app offline 2) don't have to worry about data being saved right away, it happens when ever it can 3) more reliability.

My approach will be to get/set data from SQLite during UI usage, and use a background process to find new rows and put them on the server, flagging them as synced when it happens.

Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: The question in your post does not match the title.  What is your question?

Comment: SQLite (note the spelling) is reliable if you use it properly.  Using it properly is much to broad a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question and title to match better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLIte for your scenario. But, while implementing, you can follow any one of this approach.

**Approach #1:** Use an Abstract Factory to Instantiate the SQLiteOpenHelper.

**Approach #2:** Wrap the SQLiteDatabase in a ContentProvider

Refer to this link for how to implement these 2 approaches. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

***Key points to be noted while using SQLite***

- Sqlite takes care of the file level locking.
- Many threads can read,one can write.  The locks prevent more than one
  writing.
- Android implements some java locking in SQLiteDatabase to help keep
  things straight.
- If we handle the database incorrectly from many threads and mess up the code, your
  database will not be corrupted. **Only few updates will be lost.**

***How "Multiple Threads - DB access" can be used for your scenario***

The SqliteOpenHelper object holds on to one database connection.

If you try to write to the database from actual distinct connections (multiple threads) at the same time, one will fail. It will not wait till the first is done and then write. It will simply not write your change. Worse, if you don’t call the right version of insert/update on the SQLiteDatabase, you won’t get an exception. You’ll just get a message in your LogCat, and that will be it.

**So recommended to write using single thread and read from multiple threads if necessary for faster access.**

Answer (score 1):

> Does this sound reasonable?

Yes. Note that the synchronization process can get tricky (e.g., what happens if the server hiccups halfway through?), but that has mostly to do with synchronization and little to do with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a solution that used a SQLite db on the device to sync data via a web service to the master database. We did this for a couple reasons: offline, poor connection, manual sync.

For our solution we had a flag on the table that determined if the data was pushed to the web service. Our web service also provided data back to our application to let us know if the data was received and processed correctly. This allowed us to clean up the data on the device, send notifications if there were failures, and resubmit the data if there were previous failures.

You can use push notifications as well if you have fixed the issues on the backend and have the device resend the data to the web service. This worked really well for us.